# How to select rows where two columns in same row has max values by groups

Tags: r

I have data that consist of 4 columns (id, date, x1 and x2). For each id there several rows with same date. I need to pick for each id and date only one row where x1 and x2 is max values (in the same row).

For example, I have this

```
1 20-01-2020 10 15 
1 20-01-2020 10 16
1 20-01-2020 9 15
1 20-01-2020 11 16
```

and I want to get only

```
1 20-01-2020 11 16
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`:

```
mydf %>%
  group_by(id, date) %>%
  filter(x1 == max(x1), x2 == max(x2)) %>%
  ungroup()
```